# Цикл, прибавление чисел до 100 после их падения до 0

Tags: javascript, html

Надо сделать прибавление чисел до 100 после их падения до 0.

```
battery(100, document.getElementById('battery'));

function battery( percent, elem ) {
    if(percent !== 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        percent < 0 ? battery(++percent, elem) : battery(--percent, elem);
      }, 100);
    }
    elem.innerText = percent + '%';
}
```

Comment: Уточните, что означает "вывести" вывести значение получившееся в результате выполнения функции или саму функцию "строкой" вставить в див, или (раз уже battery) это блок который находится в другом блоке и занимает ширину/высоту от контейнера

Comment: и да, не очень понятно как эта функция вообще может что-то делать, это цикл который ничего не делает

Comment: вывести значение конечно же

Comment: вы приравниваете `percent` нулю, после чего ниодно из условий не выполнится и функция вызовется через таймаут и будет ровно то же самое... это бессмысленная функция.

Comment: смотрите мне нужен код если переменная больше 0 отнимать,а если переменная меньше нуля то прибавлять

Comment: А какое значение вывести? Тут не будет значения... все время будет вызываться  setTimeout(battery, 100);

Comment: А переменная percent у Вас не меняется вообще

Comment: на таймаут не смотрите туда по идее должно быть 3400 но сделал 100 для теста

Comment: она будет меняться только в этом файле при нужном цикле а так больше нигде.

Comment: да там хоть 99999 будет, эта цифра говорит через сколько вызвать функцию в миллисекундах. Может вы так хотите передать значение в функцию? Опишите всю задумку

Comment: смотрите мне надо чтоб эта функция повторялась через каждые 3.4 минуты

Comment: тогда Вам подойдет setInterval, вместо setTimeout. Пользоваться ею точно так же. А что сама функция должна делать?

Comment: Функция должна вычислять если percent больше нуля то отнимать а если меньше нуля то прибавлять и вызывание этой функции каждые 3.4 минуты

Comment: Вы каждый раз запускаете функцию и говорите ей: percent = 0; запускаете через 3,4 секунды и снова говорите percent = 0;  и так все время, по кругу. Разберите Вашу функцию по строкам, и сами поймете все

Comment: Так как это вывести в div html я за этим суда и пришел?

Comment: код мне уже дали прилагаю как это вывести в div.   battery(100);

function battery( percent ) {
    if(percent !== 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        percent < 0 ? battery(++percent) : battery(--percent);
      }, 100);
    }
    console.log(percent);
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не очень ясно что это и зачем это, но возможно требуется что-то подобное ...

```js
battery(100, document.getElementById('battery-1'));
battery(0, document.getElementById('battery-2'));
battery(-100, document.getElementById('battery-3'));

function battery( percent, elem ) {
    if(percent !== 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        percent < 0 ? battery(++percent, elem) : battery(--percent, elem);
      }, 100);
    }
    elem.innerText = percent + '%';
}
```

```html
<div id="battery-1"></div>
<div id="battery-2"></div>
<div id="battery-3"></div>
```

Comment: как это вывести в div html я ведь суда за этим и пришел?и спасибо за код.

Comment: @Андрей Никонов, извиняюсь, добавил

Comment: Да ладно я вообще ожидал что ответят только завтра спасибо очень большое.

Comment: @Андрей Никонов, на SO правило "кто успел - тот и съел", так что если не дождались ответа в течении 2-3 часов, то скорее всего он будет только через месяц-два )))) И да, если это то что вам требовалось, клик по галочке в верхнем левом углу ответа, что бы пометить вопрос как "решенный".

Comment: а можно узнать как к этому еще знак % прикрутить?

Comment: @Андрей Никонов, конкатенация, добавил в ответ.

Comment: все спасибо а когда дойдет до нуля пойдет вверх?

Comment: @Андрей Никонов, эээм, нет, этого вроде не было в задаче, нажмите "Выполнить код", там видно, что то что эта функция выполняется до того момента пока не достигнет 0.

Comment: мен интересует только первая батарея

Comment: щас буду думать как заставить первую батарею при нуле идти вверх

Comment: @Андрей Никонов, я бы вам советовал более четко сформулировать задачу. Сейчас эта функция всегда стремится к нулю, если вам надо, что бы из отрицательного шло в положительную сторону и наоборот, то  каков предел ....

Comment: Задача сформулирована отлично При падении первой батареи до нуля она должна доходить до ста и опять в ноль.и так по кругу для первой батареи остальные не интересуют.

Comment: @АндрейНиконов и где же в вашем вопросе часть про дохождение значения до 100, а потом обратно до 0? Вы ее куда-то запрятали? Это квест? Или кастинг на битву экстрасенсов?

Comment: @АндрейНиконов перечитайте свой вопрос. Про «до ста и опять в ноль» там ни слова нет.

Comment: @АндрейНиконов, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: @Qwertiy, судя по всему товарищ пытается переформулировать вопрос, но у него это не выходит.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, тут уже его удалённый ответ есть: _"Спасибо всем за ответы.Ответ получен. ДмитриДев спасибо"_, так что он вполне разоьрался.