# Разрядка и зарядка

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код на разрядку батареи. Что сюда надо добавить, чтобы была еще и зарядка, и они не конфликтовали между собой?

```
if(percent <= 100) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        percent < 0 ? battery(--percent, elem);
      }, 3400);
```

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что Вы имеете в виду? Что значит код на зарядку аккумулятора?

Comment: Этот код должен условные percent опускать до нуля.А мне надо чтобы он еще и поднимал эти условные percent до 100 не конфликтуя с опусканием.

Comment: Вам ведь уже давали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718480/266097) практически на такой же вопрос. Кроме того как увеличивать значение переменной, которую тут же и уменьшают? Распишите всю задачу, ибо не понятно, что Вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: Мне надо сделать как у обычной батареи телефона.От 100 разрядка тоесть понижение до 0 а от нуля опять вверх до 100.И так по кругу.

Comment: а за какой период он должен разрядиться? Деление в секунду или в 3,4?

Comment: Важно, что бы она опускалась строго до 0 или нет? Если надо идти до 0 потом строго идти до 100 то вам к percent нужен еще флаг: finishСharging = new Boolean(false); и при достижении percent меньть ее на true

Comment: Я плохо соображаю пока в Js. 1.Да важно 2.Да 0 от нуля строго до 100. Я не очень соображаю как это сделать.3.4 минуты 1 деление

Comment: главное чтобы не потерялась переменная elem она у меня служит для вывода в div

Comment: Заведите переменную delta, равную 1 при "зарядке" и -1 при "разрядке", и плюсуйте её. А по достижении порога меняйте значение.

Answer (score 0):

Заведите переменную delta, равную 1 при "зарядке" и -1 при "разрядке", и плюсуйте её. А по достижении порога меняйте значение.